# Radeon HD 6850 VMware 3D Support?

Tags: 11.10, games, radeon, vmware, 3d

I'm a new Ubuntu user (new to all of linux actually).  I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 x64 and have been enjoying it, but I wanted to see how it would perform using VMware for small time gaming since I find dual booting too much of a nuisance to even bother using Ubuntu at all (sorry!).

I have an Asus EAH6850 DirectCU Radeon HD 6850 graphics card and I've installed the additional ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver, but when I open a Windows XP 32bit machine I installed through VMware, I get this message:

"The GPU driver currently installed on this host may cause issues with VMware products. If you notice any issues please disable the 3D support in the affected virtual machines."

I still have 3D capabilities in the VM but they are very very choppy even running the DX tests (the spinning cube).  I've seen people on youtube and other forums saying that since the new 3D acceleration in VMware 8 gaming is very possible through VMs (and I've seen them running the DX tests with the spinning cube very smoothly).

I'm wondering if my graphics card isn't fully supported or if I have installed it wrong.

Also when I check system info (on the host Ubuntu machine) it says "Graphics VESA:BARTS" Should my Radeon HD 6850 be showing up there?

The rest of my basic system info
i5 2500k
8GB 1600MHz memory

Guest is running with access to all 4 cores of processor and 3gb memory assigned.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a common issue for VMware 3D support according to a [post on the support forums](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1987757)

Comment number 8 gives a possible solution;

> You need to install the VMware Tools in the guest to get the proper
>   video driver.

The Radeon HD 6850 card is from the BARTS family of cards - that is why it is listed as such

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I have installed VMware tools on the Guest machine already.  Could it be possible that I get the message when booting the machine simply because VMware tools does not start up until the machine has loaded Windows?

Comment: I also should have explained my reasoning to wondering if ubuntu supported 3d on this card. While looking into making sure I had the correct drivers I came across this page "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver" which says the card will work with 11.10 but down the page has a list of cards that have good 3d support and the 6850 is not on the list. The list seems to be made up of mostly older cards. Does this mean anything?

Comment: The older ATI cards generally do not have good 3D support and hence will not run graphics intensive programs well ie: Unity. The HD6850 has good 3D support on 11.10 - this should be obvious when you run Ubuntu, as for VMware 3D the support is not as good, as evidenced by the warning you receive when running in it. Your issue is likely only to be resolved by upgrades to VMware.